# angularjs $element properties accessing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with angular-dashboard-framkework and I want to get the size of the widget.

I found the [postLink](https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework/blob/master/src/scripts/widget.js#L69) function the place where width and height are correct (at least printed in console as part of the $element).
However, when I acces those variables like that

`$element[0].clientWidth`

I get a different value than the one I can see exploring the $element[0] printed in console

### correct values:

[image: the correct values]

### wrong values

[image: wrong values]

is there a better way to access those values?

I'm using jqlite and NOT jQuery

Comment: 553 == 553... not sure what the others are.

Comment: Is 108 the clientHeight?

Comment: nope, I can't see anything of height 108.